# How to remove 'undefined' on Object.keys for forEach

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach

Hi Im using node Js and im having a problem on `forEach` on `Object.keys`, in the code below when i try to run it, there was an undefined value on the first value of output. For example lets say the value of input variable is:

```
input = [dog, cat, mouse, horse, pig];
```

Then when the program runs (refer the code below..) The value of `val` (with the `forEach` loop and `Object.keys`) is

`val` = undefined dog plus the animal cat  plus the animal mouse  plus the animal horse plus the animal pig

I hope you guys understand my question, Thanks.

```
    var input = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));
    var val;
    Object.keys(input).forEach(function(key) {
        if(key!='undefined')
        {
          val +=' '+key+' plus the animal';
        }
    });
    console.log(val);
```

Comment: Why are you using `Object.keys()` on an array anyway?  If you want to iterate the array, just use `.forEach()` or in ES6, use `for/of`.  `Object.keys()` is meant for iterating properties of an object, not for iterating array elements.  While it may work in some situations, that is not what it is meant for so it will not be perfect in other situations.

Comment: Also, in your code there would be no quotes around `undefined`, but that's just a work-around because you're iterating the array wrongly.

Comment: Im using it because im getting the keys or input from the EJS?

Comment: Your code example shows an normal array.  Don't use `Object.keys()` to iterate the elements of an array.  That's not exactly what it does.  It iterates other properties too.

Comment: @jfriend00 Sorry im just new in programming, what do you mean by no quotes?

Comment: Do you see the quotes here `if(key!='undefined')`?  Remove them.  But that's just a hack to try to fix wrong code.  You should properly iterate the array in the first place.

Comment: Uhm. I dont know what to say here, Lets just assume the values of input is from the EJS (with input tags) and i decided to use Object.keys, i think i just misinterpreted the question using arrays

Comment: If `input` is the array shown then the `.forEach()` loop shouldn't run at all because `Object.keys(input)` *should* give an empty array. So then the `val` variable will never be assigned a value. But if `val` is equal to the full string you mention with the animal names and you just want to get rid of the initial `undefined` in the string, you need to initialise the variable to an empty string: `var val = ''`.

Comment: Thanks i trid var val = ''; Thanks @nnnnnn

Comment: "From the EJS" doesn't mean anything to me.  The proper code here depends upon what type of data structure `input` is.  You show it as an array.  Your code is just wrong if it's an array.  If it's something else, then you'd have to show us what it actually is before anyone can know what the proper code is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your `var val;` to `var val = ''`. When you write `var val;`, val is being assigned `undefined` onto which you are then concatenating your text. If you instead define val as a blank string, you won't get this problem. Also, as pointed out above, you don't need Object.keys since you are already working with an array

```
var input = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));
var val = '';
input.forEach(function(key) {
  val +=' '+key+' plus the animal';
});
console.log(val);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution seems fine. You just need to handle the first iteration and no need for `Object.keys` since input is an array.

```
var val;
input.forEach(function(key) {
    if(!val && key!='undefined')
        val = key + ' plus';
    else if(key!='undefined')
    {
      val +=' '+key+' plus the animal';
    }
});
console.log(val);
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript,if you don't assign a value to your variable when you declare it, it get undefined as defualt.  So if you have something like this :

```
var drink; //The value is undefined now
drink +=' Milk';// now , this will be "undefined Milk"
```

in your code you have

```
var val;
```

value of val is undefined in this line

so you just need to set a value to val when you declare it, in your case it should be a string so :

```
var val="";
```

now you not gonna get "undefined" in your output anymore.